# What is the name of the function $f_A(x)$ that is $1$ for $x=A$, and $0$ otherwise?

Tags: functions, terminology

What’s the name of this function or not given?

$$f_{A}(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text { if } x=A \\ 0 & \text { if } x \neq A\end{cases}$$

This function seems to be like the characteristic function. But this is not.

Comment: Yes, it is! Also known as the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$.

Comment: Thanks, but $A$ in this context is not a set.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read properly! I guess it's the indicator function of the singleton set $\{ A \}$, then. :-)

Comment: Or a variant of the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Comment: What is $A$? In your definition

Comment: This is actually the Kronecker delta! Thank you very much.

Comment: If $A$ is a real number, then $f_{A}(x)$ is probably called "Dirac Delta function at $A$"

Comment: @Blue $x=A$ in the title

Comment: @VivaanDaga: Indeed. I've edited.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari, the dirac delta does not take the value 1 anywhere. If it did as you described, its integral would be 0, not 1.

Comment: We can even express $f_A$ in terms of the [sign or signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function): $f_A(x)=1-\operatorname{sgn}(x-A)^2$